# Failed to connect to repository

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket

I have just installed the jenkins in mac while connection bitbucket and jenkins i am getting this errors                                             Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h https://abc@bitbucket.org/team/repo.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: unable to access 'https://abc@bitbucket.org/team/repo.git/': Port number ended with 'p'

here is the screenshots [image: error screenshots]

Comment: Please could you share how your job is configured.

Comment: i have uploaded the screenshots

Comment: Is this repo public? I see you didn't provide any credential.

Answer (score 1):

The error message in the screenshot says invalid username or password.
You need to select some credentials in the drop down to use with bitbucket.
If you haven’t configured any yet you can add them by clicking the key button called add.

Answer (score 0):

Try proxy settings in jenkins or with http only in bitbucket URL.

Hope it helps.

Thanks.

Comment: can you elaborate

Answer (score 0):

**Add credential :**
I guess that your repository is private so you might need to add credential even if you use something like 'root' and ''.

Comment: repo is not private it is public

Comment: I have already set up jenkins in another mac already , i have not faced this issues

Comment: Did you create your an ssh files with the root user ?

Comment: No ,   I need to create a ssh file?

Comment: I don't know because i use svn when i work with Jenkins but maybe this could help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21557998/jenkins-failed-to-connect-to-repository