# Jenkins - Failed to connect to repository after update

Tags: git, jenkins

I suffer from error like in the title. Details below:

After Jenkins update from version 2.319.3 LTS to any later, Jenkins loses its ability to connect to GitLab repository (error below). What could be important, it happens after rebooting host (before updating, restarting virtual machine doesn't harm Jenkins).

[Error in project configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9B2Mh.png)

What I have checked:

- repository isn't private - generally, repository wasn't reconfigured at that time;
  [Failed to connect to repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51497858/failed-to-connect-to-repository)
- ssh privilege/ownership weren't modified;
  [Jenkins: Failed to connect to repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21557998/jenkins-failed-to-connect-to-repository)
- credentials/ssh keys are ok - I have regenerated them twice (on Jenkins and Gitlab side - keys etc.);
  [Failed to connect to repository in Jenkins to GitLab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45367790/failed-to-connect-to-repository-in-jenkins-to-gitlab)
- it's not selinux related - setenforce 0 wasn't the solution;
- it's not about user login - jenkins/git user can login;
- after update, invoking command "git ls-remote -h USER@SERVER:REPO" returns nothing;

Do You have any tips what/where can I search my answer?
Do You think it's plugin related?

Thank You in advance for Your time.

Answer (score 1):

> after update, invoking command "`git ls-remote -h USER@SERVER:REPO`" returns nothing;

That is expected, as an on-premise GitLab instance on SERVER would always use the service account Git.

I would try and connect to the Jenkins main controller machine (the one which executes an `git ls-remote` when changing job settings), and try a `ssh -Tv -i /path/to/private/key git@SERVER` command directly in command line (using the same account as the one running the  Jenkins instance)

That way, you can check if this is SSH-related or purely a Jenkins issue.